# How to enable an App Store iOS App so Xcode will Show/Download/Replace Container

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

The iOS Apps listed in the Xcode Windows/Devices/my iPhone/Installed Apps list includes only **some** of the Apps that were downloaded on to my iPhone from the Apple App store. The list also includes the apps (ad hoc deployed) that I have under development on the phone. I can easily Show, Download, or Replace the Container of any of these Apps. If I remove my (under development) app from my iPhone and replace it with the current App Store version of the App, it no longer shows up in the Xcode Windows/Devices/my iPhone/Installed Apps list, and so I can not Show, Download, or Replace the Container.

**Question**: How does one (as a Developer) enable one's iOS App Store App so that its Container is accessible to Xcode without any action from the iPhone user?  That is, what is it that allows some Apps from the App Store, to have their Container accessible to Xcode?

**Additional Information**

Systems info:  MacOSX 10.11, Xcode 6.4, iOS 7.1.2, iPhone 4S.

Note:  On a iPhone 4/iOS 7.1.2, I do not see App Store apps in the Xcode Installed Apps list, nor do I see them on an iPhone 6+/iOS 8.4.1.

Comment: It has to be a development build installed. You can't do what you want with App Store builds.

Comment: Not true!  I have at least 7 apps ( such as LifeLock, Bing, and Redbox ) on my iPhone that were downloaded from the App Store, whose Containers are accessible from Xcode.

Comment: I've never seen any App Store apps appear for me. Strange.